# Chrome Icon while resizing with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have made some implementation of resizing the elements within javascript

```
this.resize = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!this.isResizable()) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.isHorizontal()) {
            this.resizeHorizontally(event);
        } else {
            this.resizeVertically(event);
        }
    };

    this.resizeHorizontally = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const target = event.target;
        const offsetFromScreen = window.innerHeight - target.parentElement.clientHeight;
        const parentHeight = target.parentElement.clientHeight;
        const dragRelPosY = event.clientY - offsetFromScreen;
        if (dragRelPosY > 0) {
            this.setRatio(parentHeight, dragRelPosY);
        }
    };

    this.resizeVertically = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const target = event.target;
        const parentOffsetFromScreen = target.parentElement.offsetLeft;
        const parentWidth = target.parentElement.clientWidth;
        const dragRelPosX = event.clientX - parentOffsetFromScreen;
        if (dragRelPosX > 0) {
            this.setRatio(parentWidth, dragRelPosX);
        }
    };
```

So it is resizing this element. It works properly but i would like to disable "restrict" icon while resizing. It is happening in chrome. Can anybody give me some hints please?

## UPDATE 1 :

-screenshot added - this icon shows up while resizing. I want to get rid of it.

[image: restrict icon]

Thanks,

Regards,

Martin.

Comment: can you show us a fiddle or codepen? it will help us to understand and solve your issue quickly.

Comment: hi a sent screen shot... It is just a part of code. I would like to have "doublearrow" instead...

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished by using the css `cursor` property. You could have something like this in css:

```
.verticalResize {
    cursor: n-resize;
}
.horizontalResize {
    cursor: e-resize;
}
```

and add these classes to your resize elements.

Alternatively you can add the property inline in JS (not reccomended), by setting the `element.style.cursor` property to either `n-resize` or `e-resize`.

Comment: Hello, while mouse button is held and i am resizing it, the "restrict" icon shows also with your hint

Comment: Ah! this is most likely caused by the default handling of `ondrag` event, which basically doesn't allow anything to be dragged. What you can do is disable the default behaviour like this: `element.ondrag = function (event) { event.preventDefault(); }`

Comment: nope. Now i am unable to store dragged/resized location... size is never changed and moreover i can still see that icon

Comment: I see. Unfortunately it's quite difficult to guess what other stuff you've got going on without a minimal fiddle or codepen that reproduces the problem.

Comment: just when clicked while resizing i can see icon shown on img